# Getting postgres connected in docker-compose

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

So I have a successfully built image where I have `postgres` mounted as a volume, however I keep getting `django.db.utils.OperationalError:` could not connect to server: Connection refused- when I ran `docker-compose up`. My `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM python:3.10-slim-buster

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /track

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install libpq-dev gcc \
    && pip install --upgrade pip \
    && pip install --default-timeout=100 -r requirements.txt


COPY . .

ENV DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE track.settings

EXPOSE 8000
```

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  django:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
    - .:/track
    ports:
    - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres:9.6.10-alpine
    restart: always
    user: postgres
    volumes:
    - track_db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASS: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres

volumes:
  track_db: {}
```

Please, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you updated your `DATABASE` setting in django to connect to `db` with the correct credentials?

Answer (score 0):

Jango service must be linked to db:

```
services:
  django:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - .:/track
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db
```

Now you can connect to db by container hostname

Comment: Thank you @Andrew unfortunately I still have that connection refused error

Comment: May be in django scripts wrong credentials? And DB in container has been started successfully?